# Union a table with a synthetic table to get result even if query result is empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data table which i want to select some fields filtering by date.
If the result is empty, based on the sysdate I need to decide if it is ok or not.
To be able to do that I am creating a synthetic table with a flag field which I expect to be populated in result set even if there is no data in my actual table at that date.

```
WITH const AS (
 SELECT 
     'NAME 1' AS name,
      (CASE WHEN TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') < TO_TIMESTAMP('01:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag
 FROM
      Data_Table
 UNION
 SELECT
      'ANY NAME' AS name,
       (CASE WHEN TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') < TO_TIMESTAMP('01:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag )
SELECT Data_Table.sysname, const.flag FROM const LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Table ON Data_Table.sysname = const.name WHERE Data_Table.date=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

I expect to get results like below:

```
sysname       flag

Name1          1
(null)         1
```

But getting empty result if there is no data with that date.

Comment: Why would you ever expect a `NULL` value in the `sysname` column given that neither of the two sides of the union can have a `NULL` there?

Comment: I put it to represent empty result for sysname, not for actual NULL value. My main point is to be able to get the flag populated even though there is no data  for sysname.

Comment: `CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < TRUNC( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as flag` does not rely on converting to and from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's general example. If I understand correctly you need to be able to return a value even if query returns no rows:

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' table_name FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
)
/
```

The result is 1 as there is no table as 'YOUR_TABLE' in my database. But if I put a valid table name then i will get results from the top query. If not then always get 1 or any other value from second query. The table names in both queries must be the same. The second one is a copy of the top one.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in your last statement that is

```
SELECT Data_Table.sysname, const.flag 
  FROM const 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Table 
    ON Data_Table.sysname = const.name 
 WHERE Data_Table.date=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')-- Here is the problem
```

You are doing a left outer join and then filtering the data using where condition, the where condition will never be true in this case. You need to push that condition into the join so that it does not affect the overall result:

```
SELECT Data_Table.sysname, const.flag 
  FROM const 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Table 
    ON Data_Table.sysname = const.name 
   AND Data_Table.date=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```